# Add an external AAR library to AOSP for internal use from java in frameworks/base

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to include an external AAR library which has .jar, .so and res files inside.

I found plenty of ways to include an AAR lib, but to APK apps.

This external AAR lib should provides his namespaces solely to be consumed internally for AOSP development.
ONLY from Java files in frameworks/base/core/java/android/*

So far, I've tried to include the lib through frameworks/base/Android.bp.

```
android_library_import {
    name: "mylib",
    aars: ["libs/mylib/mylib.aar"],
    sdk_version: "current",
}
```

```
java_library {
    name: "framework-minus-apex",
    defaults: ["framework-minus-apex-defaults"],
    installable: true,
    static_libs: ["mylib"],
    // For backwards compatibility.
    .....
    .....
}
```

However soong throws an error:

```
Error: out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/framework-minus-apex/android_common/aligned/framework-minus-apex.jar contains class file com.mylib.myclass, whose package name "com.mylib" is empty or not in the allow list build/soong/scripts/check_boot_jars/package_allowed_list.txt of packages allowed on the bootclasspath.
```

This error can be fixed by adding the namespace of the package to build/soong/scripts/check_boot_jars/package_allowed_list.txt

```
com\.mylib
com\.mylib\..*
```

But this has major inconveniences:

- Each dependencies namespaces of the AAR lib must be added to package_allowed_list.txt
- When an APK has a dependency on any of the package namespaces newly added to package_allowed_list.txt, then classes/methods will be imported from the framework/system instead of the ones brought by the APK, which will break many APKs.

How to add an external AAR library to be available and consumed internally ONLY from Java files in frameworks/base/core/java/android/* ?